# PHP get final redirect url

Tags: php, curl, redirect

I like to get the final redirect url from the this: http://thatsthem.com/searching?ff=true&q0=Rob+Stott which actually redirects to this: http://thatsthem.com/search/Rob-Stott/325712f7

I tried the answers from other stackoverflow answers which works for other websites but not for the above link. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of this particular site, the redirection is done through JavaScript with `window.location.replace()` so you'll need to look in the body of the response:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://thatsthem.com/searching?ff=true&q0=Rob+Stott");
$html = curl_exec($c);
$redirection_url = preg_match("/window\.location\.replace\('(.*?)'\)/", $html, $m) ? $m[1] : null;
echo $redirection_url; // http://thatsthem.com/search/Rob-Stott/325712f7
```